# Updating variable in a Fortran do while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, fortran

I'm trying to fix a problem with a code written in Fortran 90 thant seeks the solution of a non-linear equation by means of the secant method. As usual, it iterates until the difference between two subsequent iterations (called 'xdelta') is less than a fixed tolerance ('tolerr=1.0e-2'). 
But the DO WHILE loop does not seem to update the value of delta, and anytime the loop restarts delta takes its initial value (that I conventionally fixed to 2*tolerr):

real(kind=8) function secant(xa,xb,func) !This program find the solution of a generic equation f(x)=0 written in the external function "f_x":

```
real(kind=8) function secant(xa,xb,func)
implicit none
integer :: k,iter
real(kind=8) :: zerok,xa,xb,xdelta,tolerr,xkp1,xk
real(kind=8), external :: func
tolerr=1.0d-2
xdelta=2.0d0*tolerr
xk=xa
do while (xdelta>tolerr)
   write(*,*) '(1)',xdelta,abs(xkp1-xk),tolerr
   xkp1=zerok(xk,xb,func)
   write(*,*) '(2)',xdelta,abs(xkp1-xk),tolerr
   xdelta=abs(xkp1-xk)
   write(*,*) '(3)',xdelta,abs(xkp1-xk),tolerr
   xk=xkp1
   write(*,*) '(4)',xdelta,abs(xkp1-xk),tolerr
end do
secant=xk
return
end function secant
```

I obtain the following output:

```
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 1.5429133782163262E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 1.5429133782163262E-003 1.5429133782163262E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 1.5429133782163262E-003 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 3.2309407833963633E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 3.2309407833963633E-003 3.2309407833963633E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 3.2309407833963633E-003 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 5.0784338964149356E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 5.0784338964149356E-003 5.0784338964149356E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 5.0784338964149356E-003 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 7.1007488295435905E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 7.1007488295435905E-003 7.1007488295435905E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 7.1007488295435905E-003 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 9.3147760489955544E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 9.3147760489955544E-003 9.3147760489955544E-003 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 9.3147760489955544E-003 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2.0000000000000000E-002 749999.99998890515 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 2.0000000000000000E-002 1.1739104287698865E-002 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 1.1739104287698865E-002 1.1739104287698865E-002 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 1.1739104287698865E-002 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 1.1739104287698865E-002 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(2) 1.1739104287698865E-002 2813405822.4623795 1.0000000000000000E-002
(3) 2813405822.4623795 2813405822.4623795 1.0000000000000000E-002
(4) 2813405822.4623795 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
(1) 2813405822.4623795 0.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000E-002
```

then the program stops since it gives a segmentation fault, but for other reasons I know. As you can see, for each (1) and (2) the value of delta is restored to 2*tolerr=2e-2.

I think that the problem must be in the rest of the program, since the function 'secant' regularly works with other functions. The name 'xdelta' is not used in other parts of the program. Could you please have an idea of what may cause the problem?

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions and add a version tag to version specific questions (this one is not version specific). See also please [ask] and [mcve], because we need to see your code probably in a more complete example, not just one function. Do you use modules? Be aware that `real(8)` is ugly and not portable.

Comment: I think the problem is with `zerok` because it stops there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, for each (1) and (2) the value of delta is restored to
>   2*tolerr=2e-2.

For the first five calls to your function, `xdelta` is effectively lower than `tolerr`. So, the while loop exits and what you see with the next "(1)" is the next call to the function, hence the reset of `xdelta` to `0.02`.

When the criterion is not met at the sixth iteration, the value of `xdelta` is retained at the loop "looping" as you would expect. At that point you have other issues that are related to the algorithm. See either [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecantMethod.html) or [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) for an explanation of the algorithm, for instance.

Also, the line with `zerok(xk,xb,func)` suggests that `zerok` is a function but it is only defined implicitly. If you want to ease future debugging, Fortran has more explicit ways to define interfaces. Look for "Fortran modules" and "interface".

EDIT: change comment on definition of `zerok`

Comment: I meant implicitly. I always use explicit interfaces so it trips me up to see implicit ones. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: good catch on immediate loop exit.  lesson to OP, a couple more debug write statements (eg before the loop) would have revealed that easily.